# Left hand side function, illegal pattern

Tags: erlang

I have a function that returns a function. I check it with EUnit test:

```
string_to_options_test() ->
    Parser = get_parser("-", ?OPTS_FOO_BAR),
    {ok, [opt_foo, opt_bar]} = Parser("foo-bar").
```

It is all right. When I modify the last line, I get an error:

```
string_to_options_test() ->                        % 41
    Parser = get_parser("-", ?OPTS_FOO_BAR),
    Parser("foo-bar") = {ok, [opt_foo, opt_bar]}.  % 43, swapped LHS and RHS,
```

Running the test:

```
urlparser.erl:43: illegal pattern
urlparser.erl:41: Warning: variable 'Parser' is unused
```

Why I can't use `Parser` function at the left hand side of the assignment?

Comment: you just can't bind a function call.

Comment: `=` is not necessarily binding. `{foo} = {foo}.` is fine, whereas `{foo} = {bar}.` legal but mismatched.

Comment: Sure, but when you have variables on the LHS, it is either binding or matching. What would you like to do with your LHS function call ?

Comment: @niahoo: I would like this EUnit test to fail if LHS does not match RHS.

Comment: But i don't understand why you want to swap sides. If your first snippet is all right, what's wrong ? So is it just about syntaxt, curiosity or you really need Eunit to behave in a particular way ?

Comment: Curiosity, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fun. The LHS expression of every pattern match *must* be a [pattern](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#pattern) while the right may be an arbitrary [term](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id76508). The primary difference is that a pattern *may* have unbound variables but *must* be fully reduced. Your LHS is an expression which can't be computed at compile time--as some arithmetic expressions can be--and is not a valid pattern as a result.